# How to execute mountAndroid?

Tags: android, macos

I am new to mac and i have been trying to set up an Android build environment. As per the android developer site, i created the **bashrc_profile** file in the **~/** location as it was not existing. Entered this code in the file.

```
function mountAndroid { hdiutil attach ~/android.dmg -mountpoint /Volumes/android; }
```

In the next step, it is told that i can execute mountAndroid. How do i do this ? From where do i call this function or execute it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. i just had to restart the machine and i could run the function in the command prompt itself. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `mountAndroid` from within `bash_profile` to execute the hdiutil attach command and android will be mounted to `/Volumes`. This will mount on every new terminal that you open. Example:

```
function mountAndroid { hdiutil attach ~/android.dmg -mountpoint /Volumes/android; }
mountAndroid
```